Pass in additional parameters to the UDP $server->on() callback function
I have an existing PHP process that receives data via UDP which then pushes that data into Beanstalk (beanstalkd not the AWS Elastic Beanstalk).  Another process then pulls this data from beanstalk (beanstalk acts as a buffer as the UDP message rate varies quite widely) and processes it before pushing into Redis.
I'm trying to speed up my process by porting it to OpenSwoole and I've spent most of today trying to get my head around it but I'm having a really tough time making any real sense of the documents as there aren't any examples similar to my use case.
I'm using the OpenSwoole compatible beanstalkd library from here:
https://github.com/xpader/swbeanstalk/blob/master/example/test.php
with the line $scheduler->add('coJobProducer'); commented out and have appended the following code:
// Start a new UDP server on 12.0.0.1, listening on port 9502
$server = new OpenSwoole\Server('127.0.0.1', 9502, OpenSwoole\Server::POOL_MODE, OpenSwoole\Constant::SOCK_UDP);

// Get connection to beanstalk
$client = getConnection();
$client->useTube('test');

// Setup the incoming data event callback, called 'Packet'
$server->on('Packet', function ($server, $data, $clientInfo) {
    global $client;
    $ret = $client->put($data);
});

// Start the server and begin accepting incoming requests
$server->start();

Is it possible to pass additional parameters into the $server->on() function.  If so how ? I've tried appending $client to the list of function parameters as well as declaring it as global (ughh !) but I've run out of ideas now ...
Ideally I'd like to extend the $server->on() callback function to do more processing but for that I need to pass in quite a few class instances, variables etc.

After much Googling around I found the solution:.
Global variables cannot be used within coroutines so the way to do it via the use ($variable) option at the end of the on-> call like so:
// Setup the incoming data event callback, called 'Packet'
$server->on('Packet', function ($server, $data, $clientInfo) use ($client) {
    $ret = $client->put($data);
});

If more than one variable needs to be passed into the function then that's possible too with: use ($variable1, $variable2)
Simple really !
